# Deadlock MySQL with Django's get_or_create on shared lock on creation

Tags: python, mysql, django, deadlock

I am running a script on my database that has multiple threads running at the same time. They are running this code:

```
with transaction.atomic():
                (
                    aggregated_report,
                    created,
                ) = db_model.objects.select_for_update().get_or_create(
                    currency=currency,
                    date=today_date,
                    aggregator=aggregator,
                    type=transaction.type,
                    **kwargs,
                    defaults={"value": transaction.value},
                )
                if not created:
                    aggregated_report.value += transaction.value
                    aggregated_report.save()
```

When I ran my script I was faced with a dead lock when the get_or_create() did not find an object and had to create it. From an application stand point I am simply catching the OperationalError and retrying.

This was the deadlock log from MySQL when I did SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-10-30 16:26:39 281472641544064
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2108849, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 2 row lock(s)
SELECT `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`id`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`currency`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`date`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`type`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`aggregator`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`value` FROM `reports_aggregatedvalues` WHERE (`reports_aggregatedvalues`.`aggregator` = '---' AND `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`currency` = 'USD' AND `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`date` = '2023-10-09 00:00:00' AND `reports_aggregatedvalues` AND `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`type` = 'TRANSFER') LIMIT 21 FOR UPDATE
*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 5 n bits 384 index Unique Report of table `phoenix`.`reports_aggregatedvalues` trx id 2108849 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 313 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 5 n bits 384 index Unique Report of table `phoenix`.`reports_aggregatedvalues` trx id 2108849 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 313 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2108848, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 2 row lock(s)
SELECT `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`id`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`currency`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`date`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`type`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`aggregator`, `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`value` FROM `reports_aggregatedvalues` WHERE (`reports_aggregatedvalues`.`aggregator` = '----' AND `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`currency` = 'USD' AND `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`date` = '2023-10-09 00:00:00' AND `reports_aggregatedvalues` AND `reports_aggregatedvalues`.`type` = 'TRANSFER') LIMIT 21 FOR UPDATE
​
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 5 n bits 384 index Unique Report of table `phoenix`.`reports_aggregatedvalues` trx id 2108848 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 313 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
​
​
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 5 n bits 384 index Unique Report of table `phoenix`.`reports_aggregatedvalues` trx id 2108848 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 313 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
​
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

From my understanding this happens because at the database level the get_or_create first acquires a shared lock to make the SELECT FOR UPDATE and then tries to upgrade to an exclusive lock which if there are 2 threads running at the same time and they both have acquired the shared lock required for the read they are waiting for eachother to release the shared lock resulting in the deadlock.

This makes sense in my head, but when running this script I basically have thousands of updates and 5 or 10 creations, however, everytime I run it the deadlocks only happen on the creation.

From what I understand the database locks that are acquired withing a transaction.atomic block are only released once we leave that block. **But my question is**: So shouldn't I also be faced with deadlocks in this part of my script considering this also requires an upgrade from a shared lock to an exclusive one?

```
 aggregated_report.value += transaction.value
 aggregated_report.save()
```

Is there also different way for me to implement this behaviour as well as to not have deadlocks at all? Or is simply retrying it good enough for this use case?

Comment: Why do you use for update , that will lock all rows that are selected, do you really need all the rowd

Comment: The idea was so that in between the get_or_create and the save when I add the value of the transaction to the report value. There wouldn't be a concurrency issue where the value of the object is saved and that thread overwrites it

Comment: You should the manual for locks in the manual. Locks are basically at least two threads try to access the **same** rows, and your job to avoid that

Comment: Simply retrying the transaction when this happens, my script works fine. I was basically just looking for an explanation as to why this deadlock only happens on creation and not on the update

Comment: It is hard to reproduce coherent access, basically you can first enable logging on SQL side, to see what happens when surf your side. Also helping does add a log on my hpn side, so that you can see which line does the SQL query, so you can check if the logic is ok

Comment: What is `... AND `reports_aggregatedvalues` AND ...`?  Testing the table name?  Or maybe `'---'` means that something is missing?  Otherwise, these look like identical `SELECTs`; are they?

Comment: Yes they are the same select running concurrently, I cropped the aggregator name from the log just for privacy sake